# indexing multiple columns in a table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, index

I am greatly confused about creating an index for a table.

Assuming that a table `users` have 5 columns, id (primary key), name, email, creation date, and update date.

```
id | name | email | creation_date | update_date
```

The initial question is about creating an index for all columns (a multi-column index). Is it generally a good idea? (obviously for a table with a small number of columns)

I know that you probably ask it depends on the query but let's assume the queries below:

```
1. SELECT * FROM users where creation_date < 'A DATE'
2. SELECT id, email from users where name = 'SOME NAMES';
3. SELECT id, email from users where name = 'SOME NAMES' ORDER BY creation_date DESC;
4. SELECT id, email from users where name = 'SOME NAMES' AND creation_date >= 'SOME DATES' ORDER BY updated_date ASC;
```

Something that I am intending to avoid is creating several indexes for every query above. So can we create a multicolumn index consisting of all columns to cover all queries above?

The next question with scattered information in the net is about the order of columns in an index. Is this the same as the parameters coming after WHERE clause? How about ORDER BY? Do we need to consider that in a multicolumn index?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following answer is for MySQL.

> The initial question is about creating an index for all columns (a
> multi-column index). Is it generally a good idea? (obviously for a
> table with a small number of columns)

No, it isn't.

If the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to look up rows.

For example, if you have a three-column index on (name,email,creation_date), you have indexed search capabilities on (name), (name, email), and (name,email,creation_date).

[Multiple-Column Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20can%20use%20multiple%2Dcolumn,three%20columns%2C%20and%20so%20on.)

> Something that I am intending to avoid is creating several indexes for
> every query above. So can we create a multicolumn index consisting of
> all columns to cover all queries above?

No single multicolumn index can cover all the above queries .

> The next question with scattered information in the net is about the
> order of columns in an index. Is this the same as the parameters
> coming after WHERE clause?

Yes.
For example if you have `where name = 'SOME NAMES' AND creation_date >= 'SOME DATES' ORDER BY updated_date ASC`

The index should be `(name ,creation_date ,updated_date)` which cover the last part of your next question as well.

Comment: _Is this the same as the parameters coming after WHERE clause?_ - No, you can write conditions in the WHERE clause in many ways and orders, _AND_ is commutative. Order of the columns in the index is more important. A simple rule would be _start with the most specific(restrictive) ones_

Comment: @jkavalik *AND is commutative*, true , but the order after the where should be the same as the one  defined in the index . Check [same_order](https://dbfiddle.uk/qTaFd5qv) `actual time=0.039`, [wrong order](https://dbfiddle.uk/GeXJ6QP4) `actual time=0.073` , in a large dataset it might be a huge difference. If this was what you meant, otherwise I must misunderstood the question and the comment

Comment: @ErgestBasha - Technically, the technical term "cover" does not apply to your final 3-col index -- because `email` is missing.

Comment: @jkavalik - 10K identical rows?  Not realistic.

Comment: @ErgestBasha that will mostly be parsing and optimization steps + some randomness, the order may matter for the parser, but after that the query is transformed into some kind of expression tree and the optimizer picks the conditions apart and decides how to resolve them. Your example is on the level of statistical error.

Answer (score 2):

1. SELECT * FROM users where creation_date < 'A DATE'

   ```
    INDEX(creation_date)
   ```
2. SELECT id, email from users where name = 'SOME NAMES';

   ```
    INDEX(name) -- or, to be slightly faster:
    INDEX(name, email, id)  -- This is "covering"
   ```
3. SELECT id, email from users where name = 'SOME NAMES' ORDER BY creation_date DESC;

   ```
    INDEX(name, creation_date)
   ```
4. SELECT id, email from users where name = 'SOME NAMES' AND creation_date >= 'SOME DATES' ORDER BY updated_date ASC;

   ```
    INDEX(name, creation_date)
   ```

   Because a range is being used in the `WHERE`, there is no advantage to adding on `updated_date`.

Summary:  If you have all 4 queries, I recommend having these two:

```
INDEX(creation_date)
INDEX(name, creation_date)
```

Notes:

- MySQL rarely uses two indexes in a single query.
- Hence, a "composite" index is often useful.
- When you have `INDEX(a,b)`, that index will handle other cases needing `INDEX(a)` (the left column(s))
- No single composite index will be good for all of your queries because of the following 2 points:
- Only the left part(s) of an index are used.  That is `INDEX(name, created_date) is [virtually] useless for Q1 since` name` is not being filtered on.
- In general, a composite index needs to start with column(s) tested by `=` (`name`) and optionally *end* with a *single* "range" tested column (`created_date`).  The other order fails to get past the range test.  Hence, `INDEX(created_date, name)` is only partially used for Q3, Q4.
- If `email` is `TEXT` (or a too-big `VARCHAR`) it cannot be included in an `INDEX`.
- The order of columns in `INDEX` *does* matter; the order of tests in `WHERE` *does not* matter.
- If two columns are tested with `=`, it does not matter which order they are in for the `INDEX`.  That is "selectivity" is irrelevant.

More: [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)